Looking for a route in Queyras/Vanoise (France)
Bonjour chers lecteurs!
Me and and friend want to hike in Queyras or Vanoise. We are aware of the fact that most huts are closed and are very well equipped to bivouac. We are experienced hikers but we don't have mountaineering exerpience. Due to the current weather conditions we are looking for a route where we don't go over 2,500m and sleep at or below 2,000m is there anyone that can help us with possible routes? We want to walk 4 days and sleep 3 nights, we like a route with a distance of 45-65km.

This might go well on our sister site Travel SE. If you don't get any response here, try requesting migration over to there.

"current weather conditions"?  Can you be more specific about when you will be hiking?  An answer now - late September - could be obsolete, and dangerous, in 3-4 weeks as late fall/winter sets in.

If speaking.french or willing to use automated translation have a look at the "federation française de randonnée" website the will have route suggestion and sell guidebook https://www.ffrandonnee.fr/

on travel this will be closed as "we are not travel agents". You will need to ask specific questions such as "is this pass above 2500m?" or "are there bivouac sites between A and B on this route?" or "where can I find a list of whatevers". Do not ask the site to make your route for you; ask for the facts you need to make your own route.
